# Get subcategories of parent category when FLAT categories enabled

Tags: category, model, navigation, submenu, flat-catalog

I override a block class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation` ([link to signature](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Catalog/Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation.html)) to create a custom menu which displays only subcategories of current category.

Inside method `renderCategoriesMenuHtml` ([link to signature](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Catalog/Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation.html#renderCategoriesMenuHtml)) I'm trying to get child categories of selected parent category. So I replaced default code:

```
foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $child) {
    //...
}
```

with the following:

```
/**
 * @param $parent ID of category from which we start
 * @param $recursionLevel How many levels of subcategories retrieve
 * getCategories(...) is a method from model Mage_Catalog_Model_Category
 */
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$storeCategories = $category->getCategories($parent, $recursionLevel);
foreach ($storeCategories as $child) {
    //...
}
```

This code works perfectly fine and returns subcategories of selected parent, but as soon as I enable the **"Flat Catalog Category"** the `$parent` variable seems to be completely ignored and that code returns all top-level categories, instead of subcategories of category with ID `$parent`.

What do I do wrong? Shouldn't `getCategories` method work the same even when flat categories are enabled?

## EDIT:

My real question is

1. Why method `getCategories` from model `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category`
   ignors parameters `$parent` and `$recursionLevel` when flat
   categories are enabled? (see source of the method below)
2. Are there more methods which works different with flat catalog? How
   can I recognize them to avoid problems in the future?

I call it like this inside method `renderCategoriesMenuHtml`:

```
$parent = 13;
$recursionLevel = 2;
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$storeCategories = $category->getCategories($parent, $recursionLevel);
```

With non-flat categories this code returns subcategories (2 levels as specified in `$recursionLevel`) of the category with ID 13.
But with flat categories enabled I get all top-level categories with all subcategories (limited with value of admin settings `'catalog/navigation/max_depth'`, not by `$recursionLevel`).

Method in model `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category`:

```
public function getCategories($parent, $recursionLevel = 0, $sorted=false, $asCollection=false, $toLoad=true)
{
    $categories = $this->getResource()
        ->getCategories($parent, $recursionLevel, $sorted, $asCollection, $toLoad);
    return $categories;
}
```

calls method in resource model `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category`:

```
public function getCategories($parent, $recursionLevel = 0, $sorted = false, $asCollection = false, $toLoad = true)
{
    $tree = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_tree');
    /* @var $tree Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Tree */
    $nodes = $tree->loadNode($parent)
        ->loadChildren($recursionLevel)
        ->getChildren();

    $tree->addCollectionData(null, $sorted, $parent, $toLoad, true);

    if ($asCollection) {
        return $tree->getCollection();
    }
    return $nodes;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(CATEGORY-ID);    
    $_categories = $_category
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'image', 'description'))
                    ->addIdFilter($_category->getChildren());

    foreach ($_categories as $_category):
       echo $_category->getName();
    endforeach;
```

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: Man, you saved my ass, thank you.  That's a neat trick - $_category->getChildren() returns a comma separated string of category ids that you can then use to filter via addIdFilter().  Smart :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 
$parentCategoryId = 107;
$cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentCategoryId);
$subcats = $cat->getChildren();

?>

// Get 1 Level sub category of Parent category.

<?php 

foreach(explode(',',$subcats) as $subCatid)
              {
                $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCatid);
  if($_category->getIsActive()) {
    echo '<ul><a href="'.$_category->getURL().'" title="View the products for the "'.$_category->getName().'" category">'.$_category->getName().'</a>';
   echo '</ul>';
  }
}

?>
```

**If you want 2 level , 3 Level, 4 Level or n Level subcategories of parent category than**
[**Click Here**](http://magentoo.blogspot.com/2014/01/get-all-subcategories-of-parent-category-magento.html)

Comment: Might solve the problem, but all the load are bad for performance, so be careful

Comment: why you are load all the category just use category id and load content only specific category only